# Why am I not able to install the psych package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, install.packages, psych, rtools

I've been trying to install the "psych" and "ggplot2" packages on my work computer and keep getting the following error (see below for version information and what I've already tried):

```
install.packages("psych")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 3.2 (installed at c:\Rtools)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
psych  2.1.3  2.3.3             FALSE

installing the source package ‘psych’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/psych_2.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1588126 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package 'psych' ...
** package 'psych' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'tmvnsim'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'psych'
* removing 'C:/Users/the.user/Documents/R/R-3.6.2/library/psych'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\the.user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm0Zlci\downloaded_packages’
```

I've installed and ran Rtools33.exe and cleared my environment, restarted my R session, and then quit and restarted the RStudio program. I've tried the same thing with Rtools32.exe.

The OS I'm running this on is Windows 10 Enterprise -- a 64-bit OS on a x64-based processor (is that why??)

Here is the version information output from the R.Version() function:

```
$platform
[1] "i386-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "i386"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "i386, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "6.2"

$year
[1] "2019"

$month
[1] "12"

$day
[1] "12"

$`svn rev`
[1] "77560"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)"

$nickname
[1] "Dark and Stormy Night"
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
# Error for library()
Error in library(psych) : there is no package called 'psych'
```

Comment: As per your output, your version of R is 4 years old, and needs to be updated in order to install the psych package.

Comment: @Phil, based on what? The package [`DESCRIPTION`](https://github.com/cran/psych/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) does not advertise a minimum version of R. Where does it list the requirement?

Comment: What happens when you try to resolve the error `there is no package called 'tmvnsim'`?

Comment: (BTW, I just removed the [tag:ggplot2] tag. You say you're having problems installing it but include no indication of how it failed, etc. If I removed the tag prematurely, I apologize, please [edit] your question and add the attempt and erring output. It might be two unrelated issues, btw, but we'll cross that bridge later...)

Comment: I thought this might be a recursive dependency requirement (i.e. `tmvnsim` required a newer version of R), but that's not true AFAICS - tmvnsim is [on CRAN now](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmvnsim/index.html) and doesn't list any of its own dependencies (on R versions or other packages). I would follow @r2evans's suggestion (i.e., see if you can install `tmvnsim` ...)

Comment: Finally, the note about `Rtools compatible` is very relevant: per https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html, you need Rtools35, not Rtools32.

Comment: Thanks both -- and sorry about the formatting -- I realized it's kinda of funky but I didn't expect SO to parse it that way. I'll try installing "tmvnsim" first, then Rtools35 and report back! 

Thanks both for your help!

Comment: Installing "tmvnsim" worked for "psych"! But now I get a similar error with "ggplot2" for the "lifecycle" package and that one isn't so easy. I'll make a new question for that one, but thanks @r2evans!! I think this one may need the different Rtools. I will also note that I've had no problem with this version of R on my macbook, and I don't use a newer version of R because (1) my academic advisor likes this one and (2) when I tried the newest version I was getting errors left and right for stuff I've easily done in this version.

Comment: wow I totall y just switched the numbers of 3.6.2 to 3.2.6, so thanks again on that catch @r2evans